# Seven Segment Cipher

Tags: cipher, visual, seven-segment

In math class I asked my friend what she did for a job. She simply handed me this note.

[image: It was hard to create a sensible sentence here]

***What does it say?***

**Note:** You may need a calculator! Then again, you may not...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is

> I SELL BIG BEIGE SEESHELLS (a misspelling of SEASHELLS?).

Why?

> Type in the given number on a calculator with a seven-segment display and turn the calculator upside down so that 3 becomes E, 7 becomes L, and so on.

Much easier than usual from you, Tryth! :-)

Comment: Now that's a technique I haven't seen since elementary school

Comment: Good ole 58008 and 1134